# How do I make Google Maps zoom with the scroll wheel when using a custom zoom bar?

Tags: google-maps

I created my own zoom bar for a Google map, but it's not working when I scroll the mouse. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom zoom bar has nothing to do with mousewheel zooming.Just make sure you don't set the **mousewheel:false** in the [mapoptions](http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapOptions) as the default is true.That way the mousewheel zooming will work regardless your custom controls functionality

Comment: But already zoomWheelEnabled set true in navigation.js.That zoom bar is created my selfits not bydefault google zoom bar.